# Stop program with ShellJs command

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, go, shelljs

I'm using `codeceptjs` with `shelljs`.

In one of tests I'm invoking a Go application like this:

```
const shell = require('shelljs')


let execution = shell.exec('./myGoApplication')
execution.kill();
```

I tried to stop it with `kill` with different params but it is not working.

Does anyone knows how to stop Go application from running?

**EDIT:**

This code doesn't stop either

```
execution.kill('SIGINT');
```

https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs

Comment: There's nothing at all special about a Go program. To stop a running executable, you have two options: Have the program exit on its own, or have the OS kill it. There's really no third option.  As for getting it to exit on its own (i.e. a graceful shutdown), there are many ways to request this of a running program—they all depend on the program supporting them. A common way is to send a SIGINT signal that the program intercepts and uses as a signal to begin a shutdown.

Comment: @Flimzy for me I use that go program in Automation tests so I want it to be cleaned in the end of test. So that I want to end it from outside. 

`execution.kill('SIGINT');` Is not working

Comment: SIGINT just sends a signal to the program. Unless the program interprets that to mean it should exit, it won't do anything.

Comment: @Flimzy Understood, thanks

Comment: this might help https://superuser.com/a/97372/592596

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/58566646/13860

Answer (score 1):

The `kill` command accepts the termination signal as its first argument.

```
let execution = shell.exec('./myGoApplication')
execution.kill('SIGINT');
```

Here is a list of all signals:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317496